# How to import a Javascript Object in mongo shell script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a shell script file called `run.sh`

```
CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb://localhost:27017/"
mongo --nodb --eval "var connectionString=\"$CONNECTION_STRING\"; `cat mongo-initialize.js`"
```

I'm passing a js fragment to the mongo shell. This is my `mongo-initialize.js`:

```js
conn = new Mongo(connectionString);
db = conn.getDB("dbName");
db.createCollection("collection");
db["collection"].insertMany(data);
```

The data I'm using to insert into the collection will be a js object which I'm planning to use here and I need it for an API as well. So I created a js file `mock.js` which has that object and I exported it. The thing is I don't find an appropriate command to import the data in my `mongo-initialize.js`.

The only command MongoDB docs suggest is `load('someFile.js')` which is not working in my case. As per MongoDB docs, it executes the js file and it throws an error if I try to load it this way.

> This function loads and executes the myjstest.js

Is there a way to import a js object into my script file?

Comment: Why can't you just `import` it like you would with a regular module/function/variable? I.e. `import { myObj } from './someFile'`

Comment: @nbokmans import/require won't work because the whole js file runs as if its an mongo shell [Write Scripts for the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) Only these methods work in that script js file